# can we use CASE with EXEC

Tags: sql-server, case-when

I want to select a stored proc to execute based on user input. Something like -

```
EXEC
CASE @InputParam 
  WHEN 'XML' THEN GetXMLData @ID, 'y'
  WHEN 'TABLE' THEN GetTableData @ID, 'y'
END
```

Can this be done with `CASE` or should I consider using the `If` construct?

Comment: `CASE` is used for inline evaluation within a query.  You want `IF` since it's a flow control construct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use the `IF` construct here:

```
IF @InputParam = 'XML'
    EXEC GetXMLData @ID, 'y'
IF @InputParam = 'TABLE'
    EXEC GetTableData @ID, 'y'
```

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario I think that even if SQL Server allowed that, an IF would be more clear.

```
IF @InputParam = 'XML'
BEGIN
    exec GetXMLData @ID, 'y'
END
ELSE IF @InputParam = 'TABLE'
BEGIN
    exec GetTableData @ID, 'y'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
IF @InputParam = 'XML'
BEGIN
   EXEC GetXMLData @ID, 'y'
END

IF @InputParam = 'TABLE'
BEGIN
   EXEC GetTableData @ID, 'y'
END
```

Comment: I think you mean to use `IF` instead of `CASE` here...This is invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes @JNK is right, I had tried the above code earlier, and it had not worked.

Comment: @neuDev33 ok, you may use `IF` then. I was using Sybase-ASE syntax :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use CASE, but you'll have to use EXEC (cmd):

```
DECLARE 
@cmd VARCHAR(200)
, @InputParam VARCHAR(5) ='TABLE'
, @ID INT =1

SELECT @cmd = ( CASE @InputParam 
WHEN 'XML' THEN 'GetXMLData '
      +CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ID)+', '+CHAR(39)+'y'+CHAR(39)
WHEN 'TABLE' THEN 'GetTableData '
      +CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ID)+', '+CHAR(39)+'y'+CHAR(39)
END)
EXEC(@cmd)
```